# Django-cms/Django SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor instead of object itself

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I'm trying to make a plugin for django-cms and having issues passing my configuration to the `CMSPluginBase` class.

This is my models.py;

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin

class Section(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SectionConfig(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(default="Usefull Links", max_length=25)
    root_shown = models.ForeignKey('Section')
```

I am having an issue accessing the object reference by `root_shown`

I'm trying something like this;

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from links_plugin.models import Section, SectionConfig

class LinksPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = _("Links Tree Plugin")
    model = SectionConfig
    render_template = "links.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['instance'] = instance
        context['Sobj'] = self.model.sectionconfig
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(LinksPlugin)
```

I want to retrieve the actual object with `context['Sobj'] = self.model.sectionconfig` but instead I get something that seems to be a reference to the object, but not the object itself.

This is what my page displays;

`django.db.models.fields.related.SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object at 0x3acb790`

How do you access the object directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin you should access object fields via the `instance` argument to `render`, not `self.model`. Like this:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from links_plugin.models import Section, SectionConfig

class LinksPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = _("Links Tree Plugin")
    model = SectionConfig
    render_template = "links.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['instance'] = instance
        context['Sobj'] = instance.sectionconfig
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(LinksPlugin)
```